# Trying to Toast a single item from Database with OnItemSelected in a Spinner

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-spinner, android-toast, onitemselectedlistener

The spinner has items that are dynamically added with two editText's and a Button.  When the user inputs text into the first EditText it displays that text in the spinner.  I am trying to Toast KEY_CALORIES from the second EditText that is sent into the database with OnItemSelected.  I am trying to learn as a hobby so, an explanation would be great.

MainActivity.  At the bottom is the OnItemSelected.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

Button AddBtn;
EditText et;
EditText cal;
Spinner spn;

SQLController SQLcon;
ProgressDialog PD;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    AddBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addbtn_id);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_id);
    cal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_cal);
    spn = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_id);
    spn.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    SQLcon = new SQLController(this);
    // opening database
    SQLcon.open();

    loadtospinner();

    AddBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            new MyAsync().execute();

        }
    });
}

public void loadtospinner() {

    Cursor c = SQLcon.readData();
    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

    c.moveToFirst();
    while (!c.isAfterLast()) {

        String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.MEMBER_NAME));

        al.add(name);

        c.moveToNext();
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> aa1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getApplicationContext(), R.layout.spinner_item, R.id.textView1,
            al);

    spn.setAdapter(aa1);

    // closing database
    SQLcon.close();
    al.add("Shit");
}

private class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();
        PD = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        PD.setTitle("Please Wait..");
        PD.setMessage("Loading...");
        PD.setCancelable(false);
        PD.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String name = et.getText().toString();
        String calories = cal.getText().toString();
        // opening database
        SQLcon.open();
        // insert data into table
        SQLcon.insertData(name, calories);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        loadtospinner();
        PD.dismiss();
    }
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
        long id) {
    /* I am trying to Toast KEY_CALORIES from the database
     * Tried many solution that failed and can't seem to grasp retrieving a single item from the database. 
     * Appreciate your help
     */


}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

DataBase

```
public class SQLController {
private DBhelper dbhelper;
private Context ourcontext;
private SQLiteDatabase database;

public SQLController(Context c) {
    ourcontext = c;
}

public SQLController open() throws SQLException {
    dbhelper = new DBhelper(ourcontext);
    database = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;

}

public void close() {
    dbhelper.close();
}

public void insertData(String name, String calories) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(DBhelper.MEMBER_NAME, name);
    cv.put(DBhelper.KEY_CALORIES, calories);
    database.insert(DBhelper.TABLE_MEMBER, null, cv);
}

public Cursor readData() {
    String[] allColumns = new String[] { DBhelper.MEMBER_ID,
            DBhelper.MEMBER_NAME, DBhelper.KEY_CALORIES };
    Cursor c = database.query(DBhelper.TABLE_MEMBER, allColumns, null,
            null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}

}
```

Helper

```
public class DBhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// TABLE INFORMATTION
public static final String TABLE_MEMBER = "member";
public static final String MEMBER_ID = "_id";
public static final String MEMBER_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_CALORIES = "calories";

// DATABASE INFORMATION
static final String DB_NAME = "MEMBER.DB";
static final int DB_VERSION = 2;

// TABLE CREATION STATEMENT
private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "create table " + TABLE_MEMBER
        + "(" + MEMBER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + MEMBER_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_CALORIES
        + " INT NOT NULL);";

public DBhelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_MEMBER);
    onCreate(db);
}
}
```

**Edit** It is Toasting the cal but every single cal entered into the database any suggestion to just show the cal that is clicked?

```
    @Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
        long id) {
    /*
     * I am trying to Toast KEY_CALORIES Tried many solution that failed and
     * can't seem to grasp retrieving a single item from the database.
     * Appreciate your help
     */
    SQLcon.open();
    Cursor c = SQLcon.readData();

    c.moveToFirst();
    while (!c.isAfterLast()) {

        String cal= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.KEY_CALORIES));

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), cal+ "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

        c.moveToNext();
    }
    SQLcon.close();
    // closing database

}
```

Comment: @Perroloco I added an edit.  It is toasting what I want but every single calorie entered.  Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need access to your adapter in order to get the selected string, so I  would declare the aa1 adapter as a class field.
When you do that, you can access your adapter from the onItemSelected method:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
        long id) {
    String your_selected_item=(String)aa1.getItem(pos);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                your_selected_item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


}
```

But I think your approach is not right... If you are listing DB-stored data, you should take a look at the [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) ;)

Comment: I never went to school for this and when I look at the android developer page it looks like Mandarin Chinese, and I don't speak any language other than English and little (barley any) Hindi when I was in India lol.  Would you give me a hand in fixing my cursor adapter.  I followed a tutorial to create this database and understand it a little. Or send me to a better tutorial you know about.

Comment: I have made databases where the user can update information but so much with adding data.

Comment: If your DB is not going to have many items (let's say no more than 50) then your approach can be used. But if you transfer all your data to an array, like you are doing, your app can start glitching if you have too many items. A cursoradapter only feches the visible items in your list, and efficiently manages the memory. This tutorial should help: http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/

Comment: The user wont be entering that many items.  What I put into the Edit above, it is toasting all of the KEY_CALORIES.  Is it possible to single out just the one selected with the code I provided above?

Comment: yeah, instead of iterating the cursor, just do c.moveToPosition(pos) !

Comment: That worked.  Thank you for your patience haha.  Really appreciate it.